# JS Delete div content and write new code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code

```
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

     <div class="item">
        <img src="http://" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

I want to replace only in the first div, `<img src = "" alt = "">` with `<video> <source src = ""> </ video>`.

To clean up div I found this code. But not the first. This is the first problem.

```
$('.item").empty();
```

To write the new code to play the video, I should use this code:

```
$(".item").html('<video><source src=""></video>');
```

I can not write a good javascript code to do what I explained you.
ps. I can’t change the first code because it’s a default slider of image.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: To get the first div only use the `:first` selector. So your selector should be `.item:first`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use jquery you can utilise [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) and [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo selector to select and repalce only the first `<img>`:

```js
$(function () {
  $('img:first').replaceWith('<video><source src=""></video>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

     <div class="item">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Bu tyou don't need Jquery to get it done. [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns only the first element that matches the specified selector and the repalce it using `replaceChild`(https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/replace-a-dom-element-36/):

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.item img');
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = '';
img.parentNode.replaceChild(video, img);
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="item">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had tried with img: first but not with .replaceWith .

Comment: No problem, if you found this answer usefull please accept it

Answer (score 2):

Try this, `querySelector()` selects only One selector, the first matched selector:

```
document.querySelector('.carousel-inner .item img').outerHTML ='<video><source src=""></video>';
```

Comment: You should explain how this selects the first element and not others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `replaceWith()` method to achieve this as below.. you can modify the selector as per your need

```js
$('img:first').replaceWith( "<video><source src=""></video>" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

     <div class="item">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
          <div class="container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have said to change selector as per his requirement

Comment: Noted thanks i have updated code with correct selector now

Comment: Thanks also to you, I'm sorry, but I didn't know I could only vote once.